# If an electron and protons are brought near what other things are needed to be done to form an atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How can we make an atom from a proton and an electron possibly a hydrogen atom.

Is it necessary to have a neutron ?

If not how can we put the electron into hydrogens orbit?

Answer (score 3):

Anytime the combination of electrostatic potential plus relative kinetic energy of the pair is negative *and* the system is subject to sufficiently small outside perturbation they can be said to be in some linear combination of the bound states of a hydrogen atom. That makes them an atom, though it may be a very fragile one easily broken up by quite minor outside influence. Over time such a system may evolve toward and more tightly bound and stable state through the emission of photons. If the angular momentum of the state is high it will require many low energy photons to drop to the ground state.

If you just fling an isolated electron at an isolate proton, however they will have positive energy (be free, not bound). In that case energy needs to be lost before a bound state can occur. This can happen by the spontaneous emission of a (or more than one) photon.

No neutron is needed. The vanilla flavor of hydrogen is $^1_1\mathrm{H}$ (called "protium") and makes up the largest fraction of atoms in the universe.

Comment: Is there a descriptive article of how this process works?

Comment: Is there An example found in nature where atom is formed?

Answer (score -1):

A proton and electron is all that is needed to form an atom. You don't even need to bring them together because a single proton is unstable and almost instantly an electron will be attracted to it.